# MVC Web Application Template

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS2008 Team System.

I am unable to find MVC Web Application template to start a MVC app. Do I need to install it separately?

[alt text http://xs1144.xs.to/xs1144/09425/mvc_missing631.jpg](http://xs1144.xs.to/xs1144/09425/mvc_missing631.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) and install ASP.NET MVC. The installer will add the template in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC Installs gracefully if you upgrade Visual Studio 2008 with SP1 :-)

Once upgraded, you can start a new project **with the template-site ready** by choosing *create new project* -> *ASP.NET MVC Project*